# How to keep python script running after it has finished?

Tags: python

I am new to this, so I am sure this is a stupid question.
Although, I cannot seem to find anything on the web.

How would I keep a script running after it has completed?
for example:

```
import webbroswer
webbrowser.open_new("google.com")
```

In this case,
How would I keep executing this code (until I want to quit the terminal (or something))?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You can just make an infinite loop I suppose, a while true construct, but why would you need something to keep running if it has finished? If you need the screen output redirect it to a file.

Comment: This question appears to be off topic. Programming questions can be asked on [so].

Answer (score 2):

You can make an loop with condition of a specific key and input in loop. when you enter right key it finish.

like

```
key="something"
while key != "q":
    key=str(input())
```

Comment: Please don't answer off-topic questions.

Comment: Why? The answer is still useful after migration to the right forum.